# Cannot install dependencies

Tags: linux, dependencies

I'm trying to install (ex.) nasm.

`sudo apt-get install nasm`

After this I get an error message:

`You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

If I run: `sudo apt -f install`

What I get is this:

`Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic_4.4.0-72.93_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic_4.4.0-71.92_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

or

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

or

If you're on Ubuntu, goto Software Sources > Other Software
and uncheck unnecessary ppa's.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2LKW.png)